# Memory not mapped, c++ in R

Tags: c++, r, memory

I'm using the following c++ code

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>    
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <opencv/cv.h>    
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>    
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>    
#include <opencv/highgui.h>    
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <R.h>    
#include <Rinternals.h>    
#include <Rmath.h>

extern "C" { 
SEXP FiltroGaus(SEXP size1_r, SEXP size2_r, SEXP sigma_r) { 

    int size1 = INTEGER(size1_r)[0]; 
    int size2 = INTEGER(size2_r)[0]; 
    double sigma = REAL(sigma_r)[0]; 

} 
}
```

This compiles without errors but when in R I type  `.C("FiltroGaus",3,3,2)` The message is:  `Errore: INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'NULL'`.
If I type `.C("FiltroGaus",as.integer(3),as.integer(3),as.double(2))` The message is `Errore: INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'closure'`.
while if I type `.Call("FiltroGaus",as.integer(3),as.integer(3),as.double(2))` the message is:

```
NULL     
 *** caught segfault ***     
address 0x200000be, cause 'memory not mapped'     
Possible actions: 
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)     
2: normal R exit     
3: exit R without saving workspace     
4: exit R saving workspace
```

Comment: Ough, the formatting in this question is so hard to salvage and fix than it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel, hard. I usually try to fix broken formatting, but this one was just too patience killing.

Comment: Please **do not crosspost** between r-devel and here. I just replied on r-devel.